# Inter-Process communication with .NET WebAPI best practices

Tags: python, iis, asp.net-web-api, ipc

Background:
I am trying to use python for sentiment analysis part in a .NET WebAPI application. (IronPython is not usable in this case as it's not having support for the libraries which are being used in these python scripts.)

Till now I have managed to use python using IPC, and calling the required scripts and getting the string results back into the .NET applications for further processing.

I also have successfully hosted this application in IIS using FastCGI.

My question is, What could be the challenges to use IPC in IIS for this approach, Like Performance, Security, Availability etc.? and what are the best practices for using IPC in IIS?

Answer (score 0):

If your approach is to achieve a microservice architecture, I strongly recommend you stay back and think again about your protocol and choose any approaches based-on [RESTFul](https://medium.com/@cknextmove/restful-api-design-microservices-f983e3ea3563).

Because you are using different technologies and platform, You should not envolved your message contract and formation on your services.

**Recommendation 1**: Use some message broker like [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/) or [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/) to play as a moderator between your service and exchange messages between them

**Recommendation 2**: If you insist to have direct communication between service use RESTFul `web-api` and just expose your needed service to outside the boundary

Comment: I think there is some confusion, Its not about 2 services talking with one another, its about starting and stopping a process (in this case python.exe) on the server when particular api is called.